# How to retain one row and remove duplicates in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with each row having like 20 fields. Among others, it has:

`table: origin, destination, date, price`

Now I want to remove any rows that are duplicate regarding only one set of specific fields: `origin, destination, date`.

I tried:

```
delete from mytable where id not in 
    (select id from (
            SELECT MAX(p.id) as id from mytable p group by p.origin, p.destination, p.date
    ) x)
```

Problem: this retains the rows with the highest `id` (means: last added).

Instead I'd like to retain only the row that has the lowest price. But how?

Sidenote: I cannot add an unique index, as the table is used for mass inserts by `LOAD DATA` and should there not throw errors. At time of load I don't know which row is the "bestprice" one.

Also I would not want to introduce any additional or temp tables copying one to another. Just modify the existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-join solution:

```
delete t1
from yourtable t1
join yourtable t2
on t1.origin = t2.origin
and t1.destination = t2.destination
and t1.date = t2.date
and t1.price > t2.price
```

Comment: Is there any difference to `select * from yourtable a, yourtable b WHERE...`, is this just the same?

Comment: And more important: What if `t1.price = t2.price`? Then both lines would be kept, but I'd still want to remove one of them. Could I do better than removing the entries with smaller id? `...and (t1.price > t2.price OR (t1.price = t2.price AND t1.id < t2.id)))`

Comment: @membersound Join tables with comma is an ancient way, but here of course, it has the same result between `inner join` with `,`.

Comment: @membersound You can try the criteria you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete t1 
from mytable t1
left join 
(
    SELECT origin, destination, date, min(price) as price
    from mytable
    group by origin, destination, date
) t2 on t1.origin = t2.origin
    and t1.destination = t2.destination
    and t1.date = t2.date 
    and t1.price = t2.price
where t2.origin is null
```